# Equal sign with a "c"

Tags: protocol-design

I am not sure whether this is common sense, but I really don't know what this $c$ means in an equivalent sign, from Lindell's [How to Simulate It](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/How-to-Simulate-It-A-Tutorial-on-the-Simulation-Pr-Lindell/454b276753de1144fab3feb8d9d38b396c2a8b3c):

$$\big\{(S_1(1^n, x, f_1(x,y)), f(x,y))\big\}\stackrel{c}{\equiv}
\big\{(\mathsf{view}^\pi_1(x,y,n),\mathsf{output}^\pi(x,y,n))\big\}_{x,y,n}$$
$$\big\{(S_2(1^n, x, f_2(x,y)), f(x,y))\big\}\stackrel{c}{\equiv}
\big\{(\mathsf{view}^\pi_2(x,y,n),\mathsf{output}^\pi(x,y,n))\big\}_{x,y,n}$$

Comment: The paragraph introducing the notation (bottom of page 3) talks about *computationally indistinguishability*, so I assume that's what it means.

Answer (score 11):

To quote the paper

> Two probability ensembles... are said to be **computationally indistinguishable**, denoted $X\stackrel{c}{\equiv}Y$, if...

This is found in section 2.

Comment: oops, I guess I should not hurry when reading a paper.